# Oracle Sum of Subquery in Select

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, subquery

I have the following statement that works fine to count the number of signed notes by user (GRIDTEXT) in a database given within a given date range:

```
SELECT 
  GRIDTEXT "User",
  COUNT(GRIDTEXT) "SignedNotes"

FROM CAPTURED_ELEMENT CE 
WHERE APPLICATION_ID = '8'
AND UPDATE_DT BETWEEN '01-JUL-2015' AND '05-JUL-2015'
AND MISC1 = 'SIGNED'
GROUP BY GRIDTEXT
```

This works and returns like so:

```
User    SignedNotes
Jim     5
Laura   3
```

I need to add a column that counts the number of those notes where they were the last user to sign.  I have tried the code below and some variations, but keep getting "missing expression" errors.

```
SELECT 
  GRIDTEXT "User",
  COUNT(GRIDTEXT) "SignedNotes",
  SUM(SELECT COUNT(CX.GRIDTEXT)
            FROM CAPTURED_ELEMENT CX
            WHERE CX.EXAMID = CE.EXAMID
            AND APPLICATION_ID = '8'
            AND ROWNUM = 1
            AND CX.GRIDTEXT = CE.GRIDTEXT
            ORDER BY UPDATE_DT DESC) "FinalNotes"

FROM CAPTURED_ELEMENT CE 
WHERE APPLICATION_ID = '8'
AND UPDATE_DT BETWEEN '01-JUL-2015' AND '05-JUL-2015'
AND MISC1 = 'SIGNED'
GROUP BY GRIDTEXT
```

This Errors, but should return:

```
User    SignedNotes    FinalNotes
Jim     5              2
Laura   3              1
```

The table structure is messy, but basically:

```
GRIDTEXT         APPLICATION_ID    UPDATE_DT         MISC1          EXAMID
<Name of User>   <Note Type (#)>   <Date of Action>  <ActionType>   <Encounter>
```

I need to know how many notes each user performed a "SIGNED" action on (working), and how many notes they were the last user to sign on (last UPDATE_DT when grouped by EXAMID, Not working)

What am I missing here...

Comment: You can't embed a select like that, and rownum logic is not correct.  Need an inline view or similar.  Can you show a sample table and expected output?

Comment: avoid surprises and use TO_DATE('01-JUL-2015','DD-MON-YYYY')

Comment: What are you missing?  A closing parenthesis for your sum function.  But, as mentioned above, that's not your most serious problem,

Comment: Added expected outputs.  Not sure how I would translate this into an inline view as the subquery is dependent on matching EXAMID and GRIDTEXT for each row.

Comment: The date values are just in for testing and will be passed by an application later, they are not the issue anyway.  Not sure what is wrong with the ROWNUM logic, as far as I know that is the Oracle equivalent to MSSQL's TOP statement.  That subquery runs fine when run on it's own with static values.

Comment: Sounds like you need to be using the analytical functions... sum,count,etc partition over.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the analytic [`row_number()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions156.htm) as TheMadDBA hinted; Oracle [says that is superior to `rownum`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns009.htm), and you weren't using that properly anyway.

This assigns a row number to each exam ID record, with the latest being numbered 1. Based on your limited sample and how you attempted the subquery, this should extend beyond the range you're querying, so I've included the lower end of your date range in the inline view (as anything before that still isn't relevant), and the upper end of the range in the outer query. The most recent date can therefore be after July 5th. The outer query uses the row number to only count the records which are most recent - because they were assigned the row number of 1, for that exam.

```
SELECT 
  GRIDTEXT "User",
  COUNT(GRIDTEXT) "SignedNotes",
  COUNT(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN GRIDTEXT END) "FinalNotes"
FROM (
  SELECT CE.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EXAMID ORDER BY UPDATE_DT DESC) RN
  FROM CAPTURED_ELEMENT CE
  WHERE APPLICATION_ID = '8'
  AND UPDATE_DT >= DATE '2015-07-01'
)
WHERE UPDATE_DT <= DATE '2015-07-05'
AND MISC1 = 'SIGNED'
GROUP BY GRIDTEXT
ORDER BY GRIDTEXT;

User  SignedNotes FinalNotes
----- ----------- ----------
Jim             5          2
Laura           3          1
```

You said you're providing the dates differently in your real code but I've used date literals here anyway. Also if `application_id` is a number, which isn't entirely clear, then it shouldn't be enclosed by quotes.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/de8ee/1)

Comment: Thanks Alex, I think this does the trick.  I did move the "MISC1 = 'SIGNED'" into the inner query as matching rows need to have that value as well.  I am still working to verify the data is 100% correct, but should be able to tweak it from here.  Cheers!